# Unable to use MVN library in RStudio due to the error "Error in library(MVN) : there is no package called ‘MVN’"

Tags: r, macos

I tried installing 'MVN' package in RStudio on my MAC using the following commands:

```
install.packages("MVN")
```

However, I am getting the following warning and error messages:

```
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘mvoutlier’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘robustbase’, ‘mvoutlier’ are not available for package ‘MVN’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/MVN’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘MVN’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/10/hv93dw3s0yd4nrlfnqg58cmr0000gn/T/Rtmp36IQ8Q/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: You might need to upgrade your version of R

Comment: It worked! Thank you